# Toolbar doesn't hide on Scrolling recyclerview in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, drawerlayout

hello I'm trying to hide toolbar when i scroll recyclerview which is in fragment, my layout also has an drawerlayout and tablayout. I'm trying just to hide toolbar and move tab bar up.

this is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#e9e7e7"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            >

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/ctb_dashboard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/white"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorTab"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabStyle"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:background="#d2d2d2"
        app:itemTextColor="#6c6c6c"
        app:itemIconTint="#6c6c6c"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>




</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/blog_listt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I have tried most of the answers which i have found in Stack overflow still i was unable to get it done. Am I doing something wrong? will someone please help me out with this trying to get this done sense 1 week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate more on what is going wrong? The biggest issue I see here is that you have the `exitUntilCollapsed` flag set on your CollapsingToolbarLayout's `layout_scrollFlags`. If you are unable to get the Toolbar to scroll off screen, that is the culprit. Your AppBarLayout needs to be set up like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[Can't embed images yet. Click here for gif.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmQPy.gif)

Also, if all you need is to have the Toolbar scroll off-screen, you don't need a CollapsingToolbarLayout. You can just have the Toolbar with `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"`, like so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

This is the best resource I've found for explaining all of the different scroll flags for AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout: http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: thank you so much. i removed CollapsingToolbarLayout and it worked my current activity_main.xml looks like below

Comment: how can i add a FAB and make it to hide on scroll..tried adding fab under coordinatorLayout but it does not hide when i scroll recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

acitivity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#e9e7e7"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            >

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorTab"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabStyle"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:background="#d2d2d2"
        app:itemTextColor="#6c6c6c"
        app:itemIconTint="#6c6c6c"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```